# how to get uniq list in python

Tags: python, numpy

i have a list like this

```
[['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]]]   
[['O_ALA_A0001', [9.05, 21.51, 64.38]]]   
[['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]]]   
[['N_TYR_A0002', [7.84, 21.93, 66.24]]]   
[['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]]]   
[['O_TYR_A0002', [5.48, 20.92, 65.6]]]   
[['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]]]   
[['N_VAL_A0003', [6.19, 18.75, 65.89]]]   
[['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]]]
```

i want remove redundant list and print uniq lines

```
[['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]]]   
[['O_ALA_A0001', [9.05, 21.51, 64.38]]]   
[['N_TYR_A0002', [7.84, 21.93, 66.24]]]   
[['O_TYR_A0002', [5.48, 20.92, 65.6]]]   
[['N_VAL_A0003', [6.19, 18.75, 65.89]]]
```

I tried, `strip`, `set`, `uniq` but that is not working; it gives the error:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readline'

```
print set(uniqlist)
```

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the list exactly? Are those rows the items of the list?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
the_list = [['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
        ['O_ALA_A0001', [9.05, 21.51, 64.38]],  
        ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
        ['N_TYR_A0002', [7.84, 21.93, 66.24]],   
        ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
        ['O_TYR_A0002', [5.48, 20.92, 65.6]],   
        ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
        ['N_VAL_A0003', [6.19, 18.75, 65.89]],   
        ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]]]

print map(eval, set(map(str, the_list)))
```

`set(the_list)` will not work because list is unhashable. Use `str` to turn it to a string which is a hashable type.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert all inner list to tuples, then make set and then convert it back:

```
a = [['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],['O_ALA_A0001', [9.05, 21.51, 64.38]],['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]], ['N_TYR_A0002', [7.84, 21.93, 66.24]], ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]], ['O_TYR_A0002', [5.48, 20.92, 65.6]], ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]], ['N_VAL_A0003', [6.19, 18.75, 65.89]], ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]]]
s = set((k, tuple(v)) for k, v in a)
a = [k, list(v) for k, v in s]
```

If you want to preserve order, you can use OrderedDict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
s = OrderedDict({(k, tuple(v)):1 for k, v in a})
a = [[k, list(v)] for k, v in s.keys()]
```

Note that my solution check whole element of the list for uniqueness. If you want to check only first elements (`N_ALA_A0001, ...`), you can use OrderedDict like

```
s = OrderedDict({k: v for k, v in a})
a = [[k, v] for k, v in s.iteritems()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove one row of nesting:

```
x = [['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
     ['O_ALA_A0001', [9.05, 21.51, 64.38]],  
     ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
     ['N_TYR_A0002', [7.84, 21.93, 66.24]],   
     ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
     ['O_TYR_A0002', [5.48, 20.92, 65.6]],   
     ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
     ['N_VAL_A0003', [6.19, 18.75, 65.89]],   
     ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]]]
```

Now a simple dictionary comprehension will get you what you need:

```
d = {z:w for z, w in x}
```

Which gives:

```
{'O_ALA_A0001': [9.05, 21.51, 64.38], 
 'N_ALA_A0001': [9.25, 24.41, 64.13], 
 'N_VAL_A0003': [6.19, 18.75, 65.89], 
 'N_TYR_A0002': [7.84, 21.93, 66.24], 
 'O_TYR_A0002': [5.48, 20.92, 65.6]}
```

Which can easily be converted back into a list if need be.

As @m01 pointed out, if you want to keep these in order, this can be done easily with an `OrderedDict` (and a minor syntax change):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict(((z, w) for z, w in x))
```

Comment: Neat! :) Am I right in thinking that you'd loose the ordering of the list though? Assuming that's the case, would using an `OrderedDict` fix that?

Comment: @m01 Correct on both counts - if ordering is important, simply changing this to an `OrderedDict` will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be unique based on the first value, just convert it to dictionary and back.

```
the_list = [['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
            ['O_ALA_A0001', [9.05, 21.51, 64.38]],  
            ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
            ['N_TYR_A0002', [7.84, 21.93, 66.24]],   
            ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
            ['O_TYR_A0002', [5.48, 20.92, 65.6]],   
            ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]],   
            ['N_VAL_A0003', [6.19, 18.75, 65.89]],   
            ['N_ALA_A0001', [9.25, 24.41, 64.13]]]

unique_list = dict(the_list).items()
```

Comment: uniquelist = dict(uniqlist).item()
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'item'

Comment: have to note, you will most certainly lose initial order of the list if you do this

Comment: for pl in pairlist:
        for al in pdbid:
            uniqlist = []
            if pl == al[0]:
                uniqlist.append(al)
                d = (((z,w) for z, w in uniqlist))
                print d